# Convert Vertices and Indexes to Model

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, bsp

Is there any way to turn a set of vertices with indexes into a Model, as in one that is actually stored inside of a `Model` object?

I ask because I have implemented a BSP loader for a project that I'm working on. I can take the vertices and indexes to render the BSP perfectly, so that's not an issue. However, the engine that I am working with only supports collision detection with actual `Model`s. I figured there may be some way to do this so that I can store each face as a separate model and still be able to keep the culling and occlusion functionality of the BSP, and to be honest I have no idea how to write a Content Pipeline Processor to automatically do this.

So, is there anyway to load that data into a `Model` without using some form of `LoadContent`, or would I be better off trying to learn how to write a BSP Pipeline processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a proccesor that build the model.

in this sample you can learn how generate a model from a heightmap.

[Generated Geometry Sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/generated_geometry)

it should not be too hard to adapt to your requirements.